# Trouble with window authentication on IIS 7

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, iis

I am trying to set up a Test server to try out asp.net (3.5) web applications before they're moved to Production. I want to mirror the settings in IIS from Production server. On my web app, application pool is set as `Classic .NET AppPool` with identity `NetworkService` and Windows Authentication is enabled. When I attempt to access app on Test server I get error "`The EXECUTE permission was denied on the object 'GetTable', database 'DatabaseName', schema 'xxx'`. I realize I can add the network account to that stored procedures security but I shouldn't have to - it works in production without it.

I am using a restored copy of the production database thus the permissions are identical between the two.  I did have to add the querying Test server name (i.e. xxx\Test$) to the *database security* in SQL server to gain access to the database, but I shouldn't have to add other local network permissions as they are included in the Security Logins of SQL (public).

In Windows Event Log* on Test server this piece of the error detail bothers me because the "Thread account name is NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE compared to when a permission error is thrown on production server the Thread account name is the name of the user.

I think I need to get the Test server to recognize the real user.  I (obviously) do not understand security to the fullest for web apps yet.  **Can someone suggest other areas for me to investigate?**  I did research this but I'm only finding things like how to change the apppool account, or identity,  not the piece that troubleshoots permissions between client to web server to database server.  BTW the production and test databases are on the same server.  The product and test applications are on different servers (both Server 2008/IIS 7).

There is one difference: ASP.NET 1.1 application pool **is not** installed on IIS on Test server.  Could that be the issue?

*Windows Event Log snippet:

```
Request information: 
    Request URL: http://server/appname/default.aspx 
    Request path: /appname/default.aspx 
    User host address: xx.xxx.xx.xx 
    User: xxx\username 
    Is authenticated: True 
    Authentication Type: Negotiate 
    **Thread account name: NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE**
```

BTW if I move my test app to production server in a new folder, it works fine.  Problem is with the test server configuration.

**ANSWER**: Set Active Directory for IIS server to say "trust this computer for delegation".  I found my answer from a 2007 entry posted by plq in this: [Microsoft ASP.NET forum](http://forums.asp.net/t/1012271.aspx?Login%20failed%20for%20user%20NT%20AUTHORITY%20ANONYMOUS%20LOGON%20)

Comment: The ASP.NET 1.1 application pool is irrelevant, unless you're running a 1.1 app (which it doesn't sound like you are).  It sounds like you need to set the app up for impersonation so it will take the identity of the logged in user, rather than the identity of the app pool.  Take a look at how other apps in production are configured to see if there are any differences in the config files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ANSWER: Set Active Directory for IIS server to say "trust this computer for delegation". I found my answer from a 2007 entry posted by 'plq' in this forum: [Microsoft ASP.NET forum](http://forums.asp.net/t/1012271.aspx?Login%20failed%20for%20user%20NT%20AUTHORITY%20ANONYMOUS%20LOGON)